# Springboot + h2 + spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto + create or update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with Spring Boot and I have this configuration in properties in order to persist data in h2:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:file:./db/testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
spring.h2.console.enabled = true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.username=userName
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database: H2
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

And everything is working well, the data is persisted each time I shut down the service and I started again. But the thing is I see on the console a info message which I would like to fix, but I don't have idea how, I've already search a lot. This is the message:

```
2016-02-16 18:36:05.042  INFO 20793 --- [ost-startStop-1] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData : HHH000262: Table not found: Employ
2016-02-16 18:36:05.044  INFO 20793 --- [ost-startStop-1] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData : HHH000262: Table not found: User
2016-02-16 18:36:05.045  INFO 20793 --- [ost-startStop-1] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData : HHH000262: Table not found: Employ
2016-02-16 18:36:05.047  INFO 20793 --- [ost-startStop-1] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData : HHH000262: Table not found: User
2016-02-16 18:36:05.048  INFO 20793 --- [ost-startStop-1] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData : HHH000262: Table not found: Employ
```

This happens only first time, because the file and tables weren't created, someone knows if there is a possibility to have since first time the file and tables created using configuration properties? I mean instead this line:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

Do something like this or maybe a trick:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create-update
```

Please will be too much helpful too me. Thanks in advance =)